# how can i generate combinations as like below?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

I want to perform combinations(adjacent numbers) on this list and I want multiplication each combination like below

```
1
1 2
2
1 2 3
2 3
3
```

After this, I want to perform

```
a) 1*1= 1 
b) 1*2+2*2= 6
c) 2*2= 4
d) 1*3+2*3+3*3= 18
e) 2*3+3*3= 15
f) 3*3= 9
```

Expected **output**  is

```
[1,2,4,18,15,9]
```

Here is my attempted code:

```
def grouper(input_list, n = 2):
    for i in xrange(len(input_list) - (n - 1)):
        yield input_list[i:i+n]
```

Comment: Please show some code with what you have tried so far.

Comment: its giving non adjacent numbers combinations also how can i filter

Comment: def grouper(input_list, n = 2):
    for i in xrange(len(input_list) - (n - 1)):
        yield input_list[i:i+n]

Comment: Kindly edit the question and add the code inside it.

Comment: Is the first part of your first snippet supposed to be a collection of example inputs and your second part is the answers, one for each example input? Why don't you show each example input as a list?

Comment: To be more precise, you want to return the sum of the products of pairs of consecutive elements plus the square of the last element. Is that correct? If so, why does (d) start with `1*3` rather than `1*2`? What if the list has no elements? Do you want the code to by pythonic (using itertools or zip or generator comprehension) or more understandable to non Python programmers?

Comment: @Rory is the order absolutely must for the list generated. If not then I have added an answer for your requirement. Please check.

Comment: I'm sorry, it may be a language issue, but I have no idea what you mean in your last comment. However, your "answers" are part of the problem--look at what I wrote about answer (d).

Comment: @saivinaymanapuram  I see that you never accept any answer So Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation). Please see the [About] page and also How do I ask questions here?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3]

for item in [a[0:m+1] for m in range(len(a))]:
    for n in  range(len(item)):
        result.append(item[n:])
        test.append(sum([k * len(item) for k in item[n:]]))

print result
print test
```

**output**

```
[[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]

[1, 6, 4, 18, 15, 9]
```

For more length

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

**output**

```
[[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]

[1, 6, 4, 18, 15, 9, 40, 36, 28, 16]
```

Simple using for loops

```
a = [1,2,3] 
tmp = []

for m in range(len(a)):
    tmp.append( a[0:m +1])

result = []
test = []


for item in tmp:
    for n in  range(len(item)):
        result.append(item[n:])
        test.append(sum([k * len(item) for k in item[n:]]))

print tmp
print result
print test
```

**Output**

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]

[[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]

[1, 6, 4, 18, 15, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

Create combinations:

```
a = [1,2,3]

# create combinations
combinations = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        result = a[i:j+1]
        if result:
            combinations.append(result)
```

output:

```
combinations [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

To compute the values you want:

```
for values in combinations:
    last_val = values[-1]
    computation = ''
    result = 0
    for val in values:
        computation += "{}*{} + ".format(val, last_val)
        result += val * last_val
    computation = computation[:-2] + '= {}'.format(result)
    print(computation)
```

output:

```
1*1 = 1
1*2 + 2*2 = 6
1*3 + 2*3 + 3*3 = 18
2*2 = 4
2*3 + 3*3 = 15
3*3 = 9
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton I think the updated code should fix his/her problem.

Comment: this not matching with op's combinations. your code gives  

combinations [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]

However, according to op it should be 

combinations [[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]

Comment: @Mahi saw that and I don't think the order is absolutely required. If it is then I will delete my answer. Let the OP confirm. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

@Vikash Singh has given an *almost* complete solution here:
Except that there is little mismatch with the combinations:

I have managed to correct the same:

```
a = [1,2,3]

combinations = []
for i in range(len(a)+1):
    for j in range(i):
        result = a[j:i]
        if result:
            combinations.append(result)

print combinations
```

The output will be

**[[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]**

And the if the list is **[1,2,3,4]**, output will be:

**[[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]**

I hope this solves OP's problem with the combination.