# how to find words out of given alphabets in ascending order

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a sequence of

```
words=[a,b,c,d]
```

And I want to find words that can be made out of them in ascending order.

the result list has

```
[a,ab,abc,abcd,b,bc,bcd,c,cd,d]
```

how to do it.

I have the code but it has C and python mixed, can someone help me with its python equivalent.

here it goes:

```
word_list=input("Enter the word")
n=len(word_list)
newlist=[]
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    c=''
    for(j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
        c.join(j)
        newlist=append(c)
        }
    }
```

Comment: using what compiler/interpreter are you running this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i generate combinations as like below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770589/how-can-i-generate-combinations-as-like-below)   question ask for [1,2,3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
letters = input("Enter the word")
n = len(letters)
words = [letters[start:end+1] for start in range(n) for end in range(start, n)]
```

Comment: that's good, short and efficient ! but you get a list of list... if you want a list of string you should do `words = [''.join(w[start:end+1]) for start in range(n) for end in range(start, n)]`

Comment: @Dadep No you don't. `input` will result in a string, and because of that, `words` will be a list of strings

Comment: ho yes sorry, because there is a difference between yours, that take a string that contain all letters and from the original question where `words` is a list

Comment: @Dadep Actually the first line is copied from the code posted in the question. The conflict is between the text and code the asker provided,

Comment: Oh yes you right ! I didn't pay that much attention on the strange code part, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `itertools` :

```
>>> import itertools
>>> w=['a','b','c','d']
>>> result=[]
>>> for L in range(1, len(w)+1):
...   for subset in itertools.combinations(w, L):
...     result.append(''.join(subset))
... 
>>> result
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd', 'abc', 'abd', 'acd', 'bcd', 'abcd']
```

Comment: Your range should go from `1` to `len(w) + 1` not from `0` :)

Answer (score 0):

## You can do it easily with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

`Itertools` has some great functions for this kind of thing. `itertools.combinations` does exactly what you want.

The syntax is:

```
itertools.combinations(iterable [, length] )
```

so you can enter your `list` of `words` directly as it is an `iterable`. As you want all the different lengths, you will have to do it in a `for-loop` to get a list of combinations for all lengths.

So if your words are:

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and you do:

```
import itertools
itertools.combinations(words, 2)
```

you will get back an `itertools object` which you can easily convert to a list with `list()`:

```
list(itertools.combinations(words, 2))
```

which will return:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

However, if you want a list of all lengths (i.e. including just 'a' and 'abc') then you can just `extend` the results of each individual list of each list onto another list of all lengths. So something like:

```
import itertools
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

combinations = []

for l in range(1, len(words) + 1):
   combinations.extend(list(itertools.combinations(words, l )))
```

and this will give you the result of:

```
[('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b, 'd'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'd), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```

and if you want these to be more readable (as `strings` rather than `tuples`), you can use a `list comprehension`...

```
combinations = [''.join(c) for c in combinations]
```

so now combinations is simply an array of the strings:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd', 'abc', 'abd', 'acd', 'bcd', 'abcd']
```